# function update cannot update in database

Tags: android, sql-server

I am trying to update data use SQL server in android development

```
String query = " UPDATE dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS SET LAST_UPDATED_USERNAME = '" + Username  + "',ENROLLMENT_SCHEDULE = '" + Enrolfix + "',STATUS_ID = '" + Status  + "',LAST_UPDATED ='" + formattedDate  + "' where REGISTRATION_NUMBER  =  IsNumeric('" + RegisBaru  + "')   ";
                Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                ConnectionResult = query;
```

when I update the data then check the data is there but it doesn't update in the database. This my data if I view data in query

[image]

Comment: Can you please add your database records and schema in question?

Comment: why this `where REGISTRATION_NUMBER  =  IsNumeric('" + RegisBaru  + "') ` ?  `RegisBaru` is numeric or string ? If it is numeric, just convert it to string and concatenate. You don't need the `ISNUMERIC()` at all

Comment: is numeric, i will try

Comment: @Squirrel i was trying use where REGISTRATION_NUMBER = CONCAT('" + RegisBaru  +"',REGISTRATION_NUMBER) and its failed maybe you have idea

Comment: is `RegisBaru` string or numeric ? Convert to string first

Comment: RegisBaru its String for database with numeric type

Comment: Don't quite understand your last statement `RegisBaru its String for database with numeric type`

Comment: RegisBaru is String type data to input data into the REGISTRASI_NUMBER column with a numeric type

Comment: i got new an idea and its solved thanks

Comment: Ultimately your problem is caused by the use of incorrect logic. Though your image is of very low quality, we can see that the final part of the where is clause "REGISTRATION_NUMBER = IsNumeric(('Registration Number: 12345')". The expression in the IsNumeric function IS NOT NUMERIC so the function returns zero. And apparently there is no row where registration_number = 0. In short, the use of isnumeric is logically incorrect for the desired goal and the content of RegisBaru was incorrect.